# Regarding superlinear convergence

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to understand the proof to the following:

> Let $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ be a sequence in $\mathbb R$, which converges against $x$ and has a convergence order greater than $1$. Then
>   $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{x_{n+1}-x_n}{x-x_n}=1.$$
>
> **Proof:** $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{x_{n+1}-x_n}{x-x_n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{x_{n+1}-x+x-x_n}{x-x_n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{x_{n+1}-x}{x-x_n}+\frac{x-x_n}{x-x_n}=1.$$

My question:
Why is $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{x_{n+1}-x}{x-x_n}=0 ?$$
I can see that this implies superlinear convergence, but why is that so? Maybe I just didn't understand the definition correctly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relation you are puzzled about is precisely the definition of superlinear convergence, if you just enclose the numerator and denominator in absolute value signs.

And as long as the limit is going to zero, those absolute value signs are moot.